# Timer in services not working android

Tags: android, service, timer

I am doing one app in that I want to call web service at every 3 minutes, everything is working fine when device is not timed out. But when its go in Time out, I think timer have stopped working.

What is the alternative way to solve this issue. I want 3 minutes gap anyhow and its not necessary to use timer, I can use anything with the replace of Timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RepeatAlarm:

```
private  PendingIntent pendingIntent=null;
    static Intent i;
    public static AlarmManager manager ;

pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(con, 0,
                        intent, 0);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                manager = (AlarmManager) con.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        cal.getTimeInMillis(), (3*60*1000),
                        pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Do not use `AlarmManager` `_WAKEUP` alarms with a service `PendingIntent`. The only guarantee about wakefulness with `_WAKEUP` involves us using a *broadcast* `PendingIntent` -- in that case, `AlarmManager` guarantees that we will remain awake long enough for `onReceive()` to complete.

Answer (score 1):

> I am doing one app in that I want to call web service at every 3 minutes, everything is working fine when device is not timed out. But when its go in Time out, I think timer have stopped working.

This was not a very good solution in the first place. Do not have a service hanging around memory all the time just watching the clock tick.

> What is the alternative way to solve this issue

[Use `AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), coupled with a `_WAKEUP`-style alarm and [either `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html) or [my `WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

Answer (score 1):

In your service class

```
  private static boolean isRunning = false;
  private Timer timer = new Timer();

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i("SyncService", "Service Started.");

    int interval = 180000;// 3minutes
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            //your process
        }
    }, 0, (long) interval);
    isRunning = true;
}
```

Hope this will give you some solution.